# How do I unit test a my class which sends emails?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class like:

```
public class StarshipEmailSender {

    @Value("${email.from-email-address:}")
    String from;

    @Value("${email.from-name:}")
    private String fromName;

    @Value("${email.smtp.credentials-path:}")
    String credentialPath;

    @Value("${email.smtp.host:}")
    String smtpHost;

    @Value("${email.smtp.port:587}")
    private int smtpPort;

    @Autowired
    private AClientFactory clientFactory;

    private Properties sessionProperties;
    private String smtpUsername = null;
    private String smtpPassword = null;

    public StarshipEmailSender() {
        sessionProperties = new Properties();
        sessionProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        sessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }


    public void sendMail(List<String> to, String subject, String contentType, String body)
            throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(sessionProperties);
        MimeMessage msg = contructMIMEMessage(session, to, subject, contentType, body);
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            transport.connect(smtpHost, smtpPort, smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            log.info("Email sent to : " + to + " in " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " millis");
        } finally {
            transport.close();
        }
    }


    MimeMessage contructMIMEMessage(Session session, List<String> to, String subject, String contentType,
            String body) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
        // code to construct a mime message ...
    }


}
```

How do I unit test the `sendMail()` method? It's got a lot of variables that are declared inside the method and I can't mock them from a test class :/ I have mocked all the other methods because they were easier, but this method confounds me. Or have I constructed this class in a bad way that doesn't allow flexibility for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

The service is currently not unit-testable. I would recommend:

- Extracting Spring properties to a separate class with `@ConfigurationProperties`.
- Autowiring all classes you depend on instead of getting their instances in the method itself. (The mentioned configuration, `Session`, `Transport` etc. - Spring should also have a [built-in support for sending emails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html) so maybe you can make your life easier.)
- Use constructor injection instead of field injection.

After that you should be able to construct your `StarshipEmailSender` with all necesessary dependencies (either real or mocked) and test the behavior.